# Is there something wrong with using window['variableAsString']?

Tags: javascript

It's been very useful for writing functions that require iterating through variables, but I've heard users advising against using similar methods.

Is there something wrong with writing code this way?

Example of use:

Say I have three arrays and want to add a value to all three:

```
array1=[];
array2=[1,2];
array3=[4,4];

for (var i=1;i< 4; i++){
    window['array'+i].push(1);
}
```

Comment: "functions that require iterating through variables" - what kind of functions are you writing that require iterating through all global variables?

Comment: I would advise you to use at least an object (`var obj = {};`) to store the variables you want to iterate through instead of the window to avoid collision or unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Also, please show us how you're using this, so we can judge the real case.

Comment: Unless you are writing something like a debugger or some other development tool, it is extremely uncommon that one needs to "iterate through variables".

Comment: adding example now

Comment: It's not iterating through variables that's wrong, it's more using the global window object.  Also note window is browser only, node.js for example does not have this object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to need to iterate through a set of variables, plan ahead and put them inside an object:

```
var myArrays = {
    array1: [],
    array2: [1, 2],
    array3: [4, 4],
    "any-name-you-want-works": []
};
```

Accessing them is still straightforward:

```
myArrays.array1.push(1);
myArrays["any-name-you-want-works"].push(1);
```

Adding a new array to `myArrays`:

```
myArrays.array4 = [3, 5];
```

And iterating is made easy (this is [the recommended way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735184/1218980)):

```
for (var arr in myArrays) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(arr)) {
        arr.push(1);
    }
}
```

If you don't need to support old browsers, you can use newer features as well ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18202926/1218980)):

```
Object.keys(myArrays).forEach(function(key, index) {
    myArrays[key].push(1); 
});
```

More info on [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Then, if you're using a popular lib like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/), you can do lots of thing easily on objects and arrays:

```
_.chain(myArrays)
    .each(function(arr) { arr.push(1) }) // adds one to each array
    .first() // takes the first array
    .map(function(val) { return val *2; }) // and multiply each value
    .reverse() // then reverse those values
    .value(); // and get the array
```

---

As I mentioned in a comment, you shouldn't pollute the global window object and also iterate through it to **avoid collision** or **unexpected behaviors**.

Wrapping your code inside an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (Immediatly-Invoked Function Expression) is always a good idea, instead of using the global scope, for multiple reasons, but that's a [whole other discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8228308/1218980) and we can achieve what you want without it (for this question anyway).

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice to stick all of your variables in the global scope. There are certain cases where it's acceptable, for instance if you have a library that you want to be available everywhere, but it's generally best to avoid using window, particularly in the way you are using it. The good news is you don't need `window` to do what you want to at all. You can just add your arrays as attributes on an object, and reference them using strings the same way you did with window (which is just a globally scoped object). Note the use of `var` to scope the object locally.

```
var arrays = {
    array1: [],
    array2: [1,2],
    array3: [4,4]
};

for (var i=1;i< 4; i++){
    arrays['array'+i].push(1);
}
```